# Android Wifi ADB doesn't detect device after restarting android studio?

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, android-wifi-debugging

Android Wifi ADB plugin doesn't detect device after restarting android studio?

Comment: it does not show when the device is not connected to `192.168.43.1:5555` (or whatever ip you have)

Comment: It is connected but I'm not sure if it can automatically connect without cable if the android device is not rooted

Comment: see [Connect ADB to a device via WiFi](https://riptutorial.com/android/example/4061/connect-adb-to-a-device-via-wifi)